# hosting web application developed using codeigniter in google apps

Tags: google-app-engine, codeigniter, web-hosting, codeigniter-2

Hi i developed a web application using codeigniter in php. i want to host this application and have to send the link for review.

I want to know the steps that i have to follow. please post some useful links that would guide me..

I am new to web hosting and this is my first task in web hosting.

I did install the python and google app api's required and did some example steps which are given online but couldn't figure out how it can be done for a web application done using codeigniter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google App Engine does not support hosting of PHP projects. There are Many, many PHP hosting providers out there. Do a little Googling to find one that fits your needs.

Comment: thanks ...there are ways to run php projects in google app still it's difficult...

Answer (score 1):

Google just started AppEngine for PHP.
I dont have the exact answer about how to install it but a few helpful links.

You can download a modified version of codeignitor(adapted for appEngine) here
https://github.com/edwardmp/CodeIgniter-AppEngine

this link is to the sample hello world program using php SDK

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installingwindows

the following link is to the tutorial provided by google about how to run wordpress in google app engine

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I have used PHP Fog cloud to host my app. It's very easy and simple. It also has codeIgniter in it which makes the hosting much simpler.